# Regex matching in online tester but not in program

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regex expressions and with the help of some regex tester i've written the following regex expression:

`Match m = Regex.Match(readText, @"/\[[A-Z][A-Z]\-\d\d\d\d\d\-\-\]/g");`

Test values:

[CP-00000--#G100]        -No match

[CP-00000--]             -Match

[CP-00099--]             -Match

[CP-00000--.base#G100]   -No match

If I test this in the online Regex tester this expression matches all the cases I want it to match.
But whenever I test this in my program i doesnt find any machtes.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(readText, @"\[[A-Z]{2}-\d{5}--]")`

Comment: FYI C# regexes don't use switches - so the `/g` at the end of your expression is interpreted as part of the regex, so it won't match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you that worked for me. Can you explain why my question is a duplicate? I agree that the question about regex expressions have been asked quite a lot. But because I've my specific expression doesn't that make the question unique? Just wondering in case i need to ask a question on here again.

Comment: 1) You should not use regex delimiters with flags - regex literals - in C# when defining regex (Dupe #1). 2) To match multiple occurrences, use `Regex.Matches`, not `Regex.Match` (Dupe #2).